# Add Item to Baseadapter

Tags: android

I want to add an additional Item to my Listview how can I do this also with a new If-Stateme? Here is the code:

This is the Array:

```
private int[] Image1 = {R.drawable.handschuhe}
private String[] Name1 = {"Clicker"};
private String[] Description1 = {"+10 heals per second"};
```

...

Here starts the BaseAdapter I need to put more Items in this also with new If-Statemnets:

```
public class ShopAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Image1.length;

        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.itemlist, null);


            ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgItem1)).setImageResource(Image1[position]);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName1)).setText(Name1[position]);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription1)).setText(Description1[position]);



            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {   //need a seperate Statement right here
                    if (getCount() == 1) {
                        if (points >= 10) {
                            updateLps1(10);
                            updatePoints1(10);
                            save();
                        } else {
                            (new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)).setMessage("You need more Heals!").show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ListView was deprecated many years ago. Use `RecyclerView` and `ListAdapter` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter

Comment: Thank you for the Tipp but can you show me a solution for my problem?